# Define font-size on html or body?

Tags: html, css

I am working in a project and our client wants to follow all the best practices and web standards. I need a little help here. I just want to know

 Where shall I define the `font-size` in my css(external)

in `html {...}` or in `body{....}` which is best and why?

Comment: IMO, `body` is enough..

Comment: Focusing on standards is good, but don't overdo it. Either will be fine.

Comment: @DanFromGermany you will never seen any element that is not in body, so setting a font-size on either will have the exact same effect.

Comment: body{} is enough u r riht

Comment: AFAIK, `body` is parent element to all the elements.. and also `font-size` is a inheriting property. that is why I said so..

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178049/css-use-universal-selector-vs-html-or-body-selector

Comment: And with that duplicate question I stand corrected. `html` it is then.

Comment: @StephanMuller for only `rem` unit. otherwise using `body` is enough as suggested in the another answer in the same post.

Comment: Sure, but since it doesn't make much difference anyway why not stick to `html` so if you ever use `rem` units you won't run into troubles. If you're looking for best practices, I guess `html` would be the most solid one.

Comment: Isn't the unit called `em` instead of `rem`?

Comment: @DanFromGermany: No, `rem` is a entirely separate and new unit: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in both. Like:

Css:

```
html, body { font-size: ...; }
```

I prefer, to use the

```
p{}
h1{}
h2{}
```

To set the font-sizes on different tags

Comment: Sure you'll need separate selectors to set different font sizes, but if you want to use relative sizes (like `em`s) you'll need to set a base font size on the `body` or `html`, which this question is about.

Comment: @ C Travel, I think u didnt get my question? I need to declare in only one tag, not in both.

Comment: Than just use the  `body{}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to apply `font-size` to `html` because there should be no text displayed outside of the body.

However both should work.

Comment: "_However both should work._" this line suggesting to forget the first line you have written. :)

Comment: But, which is the best practice. Since, I logically thought just like you did. That's y I raised a question here!

Comment: If you plan on using the cascade starting with `html`, then define a base font-size in `html`. That may be needed if you want to use `rem` units. I think it is less a question of best practice rather than what fits your need.

Answer (score -1):

I learned CSS always setting body font-size at 62.5%.

That way you get 1em=10px for other element on the body while changing

Comment: its not about the font-size in px or em, its about the best practice

Comment: read my answer % or em is additional info. Have mentioned about specifying for body.